# Android In APP Billing verification from server side

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

I have done a APP and integrated in APP purchases successfully. I want to integrate server side verification in to this APP. this is a SMS sending APP and they need credit to send messages. when someone purchase some credit i want to android client to run a web service(on my server) to verify weather the purchase was really made.

I can do the web service in my server with php or JAVA, then if its successful APP will Add the credit. I could not fine a way to verify the google payment using web, is such scenario possible. please guide me on this.

Comment: I found the answer my self , check the link bellow https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get#request

Comment: could you provide more information what you have done?